# Unable to update time in datePicker on button click in tableview swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to display a date picker and update its time on button click.

I have a table view which shows business hours as shown in the below figure 1.

**Figure 1**

[image]

On clicking the timings cell or the time button inside the cell, I am expanding the cell to show date picker, I am unable to update the time in the date picker to the time on the time button.

For example when 9:00 AM is clicked, I would like to show 9:00 AM in the date picker as shown in below figure 2 or when 5:00 PM is clicked I would like to show 5:00 PM in date picker.

Also when the user changes the time in the date picker, I would like to update its corresponding time button in the tableview cell.

**Figure 2**

[image]

Below is the code, see code below comment `//Updating the date picker`

Since I am trying to update the date picker time inside a closure, it doesn't seem to work. Can someone please advice how I can fix this ?

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)      // This displays the delete button infront of the cell
        tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true   // Allows the table view cells to be selected during editing mode

        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("DailyTimesTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! DailyTimesTableViewCell

            // Configure the cell...
            cell.selectionStyle             = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none; // Ensuring that there is no background for the selected cell
            cell.datePicker.datePickerMode  = .time         // Setting start and time            
            cell.datePicker.minuteInterval = 5
            cell.datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerChanged), for: .valueChanged)

            let startTime   = timesArray[indexPath.row]["startTime"]
            cell.startTime.setTitle(startTime as! String?, for: .normal)
            cell.startTime.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)

            let endTime     = timesArray[indexPath.row]["endTime"]

            cell.endTime.setTitle(endTime as! String?, for: .normal)
            cell.endTime.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)

            // Closure
            cell.startTimeTapped = { (button  : UIButton) -> Void in

                // Updating the date picker 
                cell.datePicker.date = self.convertToDateObject(timeString: startTime as! String)
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

                // Expanding the cell to show date picker 
                if self.selectedCellIndexPath != nil && self.selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
                    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.setEditing(true, animated: true)   // This displays the delete button infront of the cell
                    self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil
                } else {
                    self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
                }


            }

            // Closure
            cell.endTimeTapped = { (button) -> Void in
                // Updating the date picker
                cell.datePicker.date = self.convertToDateObject(timeString: endTime as! String)
                tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)

                // Expanding the cell to show date picker 
                if self.selectedCellIndexPath != nil && self.selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath{
                    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.setEditing(true, animated: true)
                    self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil
                }else{
                    self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
                }
            }
            return cell
      }
}
```

DailyTimesTableViewCell code:

```
import UIKit

class DailyTimesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate {
    typealias  buttonTappedBlock = (_ button:UIButton) -> Void
    var startTimeTapped : buttonTappedBlock!
    var endTimeTapped : buttonTappedBlock!



    @IBAction func startTimeClicked(_ sender: subclassedUIButton) {
        if startTimeTapped != nil {
            startTimeTapped(sender as UIButton)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func endTimeClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if endTimeTapped != nil{
            endTimeTapped(sender as UIButton)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To set date for your `UIDatePicker`, simply use this piece of code to convert string formed time to a date

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "HH:mm"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("17:00")//Put textfield.text! here

datePicker.date = date
```

For your second part of the question, since you may have multiple date pickers, what you need to do is to add selection change listener to all of them, then figure out which one is changed and also which label is clicked. Finally set the label to correct value.

You can use section number to find out which data picker is clicked. In your `cellForRow`, add section as tag and then add the listener

```
datePicker.tag = indexPath.section
textView.tag = indexPath.section
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("dataPickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
```

Then in the listener function, find out  which data picker has changed value

```
func datePickerChanged(datePicker:UIDatePicker) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

    if datePicker.tag == 0 {
        textView.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    }
    // keep going

}
```

Comment: Thanks.. You answered the second part of the question, but how do you set the time for datePicker using the button title "9:00 AM" when that button is clicked. I tried to set using this line of code `cell.datePicker.date = self.convertToDateObject(timeString: startTime as! String)` inside the closure as you can see in the code, but this doesn't seem to work. (However, the same works when it is outside the closure, which is not what I want).

Comment: When I set the code inside this closure like this it doesn't work (i.e on button click). `cell.startTimeTapped = { let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                dateFormatter.dateFormat =  "HH:mm"
                let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "17:00")//Put textfield.text! here
                cell.datePicker.date = date!}`

Comment: @user44776 Are you seeing error message? Are you sure that the picker is correctly connected to your custom cell?

Comment: I don't see any error message. the picker is correctly connected, when the same code is set outside the closure the picker is updated, so this confirms it is connected. After assigning the time "17:00" to datePicker, when I print `cell.datePicker.date` I get UTC time "2000-01-01 11:30:00 +0000" which is correct UTC time except for year, month and day.

Comment: @user44776 Can you add my code and put a break point there? You need to validate if `dateFormatter` object is nil or not. I am suspecting that a in a closure like this, you lost access to the objects in the cell

Comment: I've updated my above comment, the datePicker and dateFormatter are available inside the closure since I was able to print `cell.datePicker.date`. Is the problem because the tableView cell is not being updated ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148428/discussion-between-fangming-ning-and-user44776).

Comment: My answer evolved from our chat, if you can update your answer with what I have posted I can accept your answer and delete mine.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this part of the question:

> I am unable to update the time in the date picker to the time on the
>   time button

is the below code:

the issue was with this line of code `tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)` and by adding `tableView.beginUpdates()`, `tableView.beginUpdates()` and returning the cell helped.

In the function `cellForRow At` updated to the below code

```
cell.startTimeTapped = { (button) -> DailyTimesTableViewCell in
                self.tableView.beginUpdates()
                cell.datePicker.date = self.convertToDateObject(timeString: startTime as! String)
                if self.selectedCellIndexPath != nil && self.selectedCellIndexPath == indexPath {
                    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.setEditing(true, animated: true)   // This displays the delete button infront of the cell
                    self.selectedCellIndexPath = nil
                } else {
                    self.selectedCellIndexPath = indexPath
                }

                tableView.endUpdates()

                return cell

            }
```

In the class DailyTimesTableViewCell, updated to the below code

```
class DailyTimesTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate {

typealias  buttonTappedBlock = (_ button:UIButton) -> DailyTimesTableViewCell
    var startTimeTapped : buttonTappedBlock!
    var endTimeTapped : buttonTappedBlock!
    @IBAction func startTimeClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {

        if startTimeTapped != nil {
            startTimeTapped(sender as UIButton)
        }
   }

}
```